# RStudio: Organizing the means and medians of groups by factor level

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

Please forgive me because I'm extremely new to R Studio, so I'd appreciate if you could help via pointing me to documentation or something of the sort.

I have a data frame called `GSS` that has very, very many unlabeled rows and two columns labeled `COLOR` and `STAGE`, among other irrelevant columns. `STAGE` is comprised of random values between 1 and 100, while `COLOR` can only be between 1 and 4. I have also created a factor `FCOL`, which categorizes and enumerates the frequency of values in `COLOR` where 1=Red, 2= Blue, 3=Green, and 4=Yellow.

I'd like to create a table that organizes the means and medians of the values in `STAGE` sharing the same color. I attempted to do so with this:

```
stats <- GSS %>%
  group_by(COLOR) %>%
  summarize(mean_stage = mean(STAGE),
            median_stage = median(STAGE))
```

This successfully calculates the mean and median stage per color, as shown by `stats$mean_stage` and `stats$median_stage` producing the right values in the expected color order, but running `table(stats)` produces a very difficult to read series of tables full of 1s and 0s that seem to give no indication of which color corresponds to which number. Ideally, I'd like to be able to group them by their level in my factor `FCOL`, where I have a column with "Red, Blue, Green, Yellow" next to a column with the corresponding means and a column with the corresponding values. However, writing `group_by(FCOL)` gives me an error telling me that Column 'FCOL' is unknown.

How can I create this table the way I want? I've been doing lots of searching, but I can't seem to find anything that explains how to connect my data frame back to the factor I've already created. I'm using the libraries tidyverse and dplyr.

Comment: Please show a small reproduciible example with `dput` and expected output  Please check the column names of `GSS` with `colnames(GSS)`  The `stats` dataset only have the 'COLOR' and the `mean_stage`, `median_stage` columns and not 'FCOL'  If you want to create these new columns, then use `mutate` instead of `summarise`

Comment: You should look at `stats` directly, not `table(stats)`. It will have four rows with the stats for the four colors. To use `FCOL` instead of `COLOR`, add it as a column in `GSS` and `group_by(FCOL)`.

Comment: @KentJohnson You're right, `print.data.frame(stats)` makes it display how I expect it. How do I add `FCOL` to `GSS`? That sounds like it'll solve my problem. I'd prefer to have it replace `COLOR` if possible.

Comment: @KentJohnson never mind, I figured it out. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting issue was fixed by replacing `table(stats)` with `print.data.frame(stats)`. I then replaced `COLOR` with `FCOL` with `gss <- gss %>% mutate(COLOR = FCOL)`.